# How well will the Toshbia Chromebook 2 (celeron 3215U processor) running Ubuntu be suited for local android and web development (not cloud)?

Tags: android, chromebook

I'm looking for a portable slim cheap laptop just for development. I will be using it for Android development and Web development (Rails, PHP or Python). All this will be done locally and not on the cloud.

The Toshbia Chromebook 2 (with Celeron 3215U) has caught my eye. It meets all requirements (4GB RAM, excellent screen and I dont care about the storage) but only worried about the processor. I'm planning to install a linux distro (probably Ubuntu) and do my development. How well will it perform with my above mentioned usage?

Note: I dont play games or run media intensive applications. I wil have quite a few tabs open in chrome while i develop.

PS: Also suggest any other laptops that can match my requirements. Budget $400.

Answer (score 0):

Frm my experience using the acer chromebook c720, the celeron processor, although works great with ubuntu in terms of hardware support (I suggest HugeGreenBug's custom build), chokes a bit at processor-intensive tasks like compiling. If your development involves such tasks, I suggest you go with the acer c720 with core i3.

Comment: Since you have experience with chromebook, let me ask you. What if i open up 20 tabs in chrome (incl. video, music, cloud edit etc) and a word processor, torrent download at once. Will switching between processes be a trouble ? Will computer slow down? in 4GB RAM and celeron 3215U